# TabIncorrect syntax near '–'

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Select * from YogaTimeTable;

Delete from YogaTimeTable
Where yogaID in (select ytt.YogaID, yr.roomCapacity * yt.classPrice as grossProfit,
ytt.duration / 60 as durationInHours
from YogaRooms yr, YogaTypes yt, YogaTimeTable ytt 
where ytt.RoomNum = yr.roomNum and 
grossProfit – (yr.CostPerHour * durationInHours) < 200);

Select * from YogaTimeTable;
```

I don't know what is wrong with my code but whenever I try to run it it says incorrect syntax near -. The Goal is to delete any classes that make less than 200$ Profit. The Tables are included.
Thanks
[image: Tables]

Comment: can you try "(grossProfit – (yr.CostPerHour * durationInHours)) < 200"

Comment: Same Error.. Incorrect syntax near '–'.

Comment: your character is "–", minus is "-". It can be a mistake about that also.

Comment: thanks man.. now it says Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'exists'.                  
Select * from YogaTimeTable; 

Delete from YogaTimeTable 
Where yogaID exists (select ytt.YogaID, yr.roomCapacity * yt.classPrice as grossProfit, 
ytt.duration / 60 as durationInHours 
from YogaRooms yr, YogaTypes yt, YogaTimeTable ytt 
where ytt.RoomNum = yr.roomNum and 
(yr.roomCapacity * yt.classPrice) - (yr.CostPerHour * (ytt.duration / 60)) < 200);

Answer (score 0):

You have other character which is called EN DASH(U+2013) `–` but you need HYPHEN-MINUS(U+002D) `-`.

Comment: Select * from YogaTimeTable;

Delete from YogaTimeTable
Where yogaID in (select ytt.YogaID, yr.roomCapacity * yt.classPrice as grossProfit,
ytt.duration / 60 as durationInHours
from YogaRooms yr, YogaTypes yt, YogaTimeTable ytt 
where ytt.RoomNum = yr.roomNum and 
(yr.roomCapacity * yt.classPrice) - (yr.CostPerHour * (ytt.duration / 60)) < 200);

Select * from YogaTimeTable;

Comment: Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
://

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors in subquery in DELETE statement - column aliases are not seen in WHERE clause. Rewrite this subquery in this way -

```
SELECT
  ytt.YogaID
FROM
  YogaRooms yr, YogaTypes yt, YogaTimeTable ytt 
WHERE
  ytt.RoomNum = yr.roomNum
  AND (yr.roomCapacity * yt.classPrice – (yr.CostPerHour * ytt.duration / 60) < 200
```

Check the condition. Then, if it is correct, put this query into DELETE statement.